# How to increase Intel HD Graphics dedicated video memory in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, memory, graphics-card

I have a Windows 8 system. Its specification is-

- 4 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD
- Intel Pentium Dual Core processor (2.9 GHz each)

My system has Intel HD Graphics installed in it(Version- 9.17.10.3347). I just tried to increase the dedicated video memory as described here- http://www.pvladov.com/2013/10/increase-intel-hd-graphics-dedicated-video-memory.html, but I can't. My motherboard is Asus and I was unable to find an option named 'Chip Configuration'.

How can I increase the dedicated video memory ?

Comment: why do you want to do this? Does any application need more GPU RAM?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, FIFA 2014

Comment: the integrated Intel HD is too slow for playing games. Buy a betetr gaming cad like http://www.nvidia.com/gtx-700-graphics-cards/gtx-770/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here that you need to deal with or be aware of:

You cannot increase the memory assigned to integrated graphics beyond what has been determined appropriate by the system manufacturer.

Most systems using only integrated graphics prevent you from even adjusting the amount of memory assigned, and those that do allow you to adjust the amounts in the BIOS only allow you to choose between a few preset selections.

If you were to provide the actual model number of the ASUS mainboard you are using, we may be able to look up specific settings for your system. The article you linked in your question is very generic.

So, in short, if you're not finding the "Chipset Configuration" area you're looking for in your system BIOS, you are not going to be able to adjust your video memory.

Also, as others noted, integrated graphics will not be enough to allow you to run this game effectively.

EA notes the minimum system requirements for this system are (http://help.ea.com/en/article/fifa-14-system-requirements/):

> "Video: 3D accelerated 256 MB video card with support for Pixel Shader
>   3.0 Minimum Supported Video Cards: ATI Radeon HD 3600, NVIDIA GeForce 6800GT"

And the recommended requirements are:

> Video: Nvidia 8800 GT / ATI Radeon HD 4650

Given that you describe your processor as a "Pentium Dual Core Process", I would guess your computer is around 10 years old, and even installing a better graphics card will not, in my opinion, be enough to run this game well. You should consider purchasing a new computer with current hardware in order to play this game.